# Default Priors for Intercept and Standard Deviations in R package brms

Tags: bayesian, glmm, prior, stan, brms

The only resource I found explaining the default priors in brms is [its manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/index.html) (newest version, updated 03/14/2021) for function set_prior().

For the intercept, the manual does not specify how the default prior is selected. When I fit a generalized linear mixed-effects model (GLMM), it appeared to be Normal(0, scale), but I am not sure how the scale was determined.

For standard deviations, such as the ones for group-level random effects and for the Gaussian auxiliary parameter (residual standard deviation), the default prior is a half student-t distribution t(3, 0, scale). The manual describes that the scale "depends on the standard deviation of the response after applying the link function. Minimally, the scale parameter is 2.5". However I cannot find any details on this dependency.

In comparison, the default priors implemented by another package [rstanarm has clear descriptions](https://mc-stan.org/rstanarm/articles/priors.html) on their default prior choices especially on how the scales are determined.

I wonder if anyone knows more about
(1) the default prior distribution for the intercept,
(2) how the scale is determined for the half student-t for the standard deviations in brms.

Answer (score 1):

*brms* seems to use a combination of uniform priors and weakly informative priors based on the data you give it. You can run brms::prior_summary(your_model_fit_object) to see what it has chosen. If the prior is blank, that means it has chosen a uniform prior.